# Get all the conversations from a page with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My main goal is to make a dashboard on my personal website that contains all the conversations from my facebook page and where we could also send messages.

The idea here would be that my support team just logs into my website and could answer client's questions asked through the facebook page.

The thing is that I want to get all the chat logs to create a view for the support team to have a clear view of the conversation. I know that there is a reference called [/{conversation-id}/messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/conversation/messages) but I can't seem to figure out how to get a list of all the conversation-ids available on the page.

I guess it would make it easier to do it with these informations.

Comment: You start at [/page-id/conversations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations).

Comment: Perfect man, you saved my life. You can put it as an answer if you want so that i put it as solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all conversations a page is involved in, you start at `/page-id/conversations`

From there you get the conversation threads, and the individual messages can be found in those.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations

Comment: Hello CBroe, how do you get the actual message text in a conversation? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379545/how-to-get-facebook-page-conversation-or-messages-with-the-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

1. List page conversations: `/{page-id}/conversations`
2. List messages in the conversation: `/{conversation-id}/messages`
3. Get item: `/{message-id}`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/message