# How to get Facebook Page Conversation or Messages with the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

what is the correct way to get the conversation/messages on a Facebook page?

I am using:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{page-id}/conversations` which returns

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "t_XXXX",
            "updated_time": "2022-05-25T12:37:30+0000"
        }
}
```

Now trying to get the messages with `https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{page-id}/conversations/t_XXXX/messages` throws

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unknown path components: /messages",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2500,
        "fbtrace_id": "asdf"
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried to put the the `conversation id` as a query parameter, but it only returns empty `data: []`

Comment: You need to leave out the `{page-id}/conversations/` part, the `t_XXXX` on its own is the identifier you need to query: `https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/t_XXXX/messages `

Comment: When I try this endpoint it does not return the `message` text but just the `id` and `created_time` like this `{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "m_XX",
            "created_time": "2022-05-18T05:47:46+0000"
        }
}`

Comment: That's because you have to _ask_ for the `fields` you want, otherwise you will only get the very limited default set.